Using a PowerShell script how would I set specific permissions when creating a SharePoint site template
I am using this as a guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview#anatomy-of-a-site-script
As usual most MS documentation leave out the most important parts :).
My script uses JSON:
$site_script = @"
 {
   "$schema": "schema.json",
     "actions": [
        {
            "verb": "setSiteExternalSharingCapability",
            "capability": "Disabled"
        },
        {
           "verb": "setSitePermission",
           "permissionKind": "UseClientIntegrationFeatures",
           "principal": "Everyone",
           "propagateAcl": false,
           "remove": true
       },
       {
           "verb": "setSiteBranding",
           "themeName": "SiteTemplateBranding",
           "navigationLayout": "Megamenu",
           "headerLayout": "Compact",
           "headerBackground": "Strong",
           "showFooter": true
        }, 
        {
           "verb": "setSiteLogo",
           "url": "https://etc..."
        }
     ],
       "bindata": { }, 
       "version": 1
 }
"@
$addSiteScript = Add-SPOSiteScript -Title $themeName -Content $site_script -Description "Communication site which removes data export for modern experience and adds branding."
Write-Host $addSiteScript.Id

Add-SPOSiteDesign -Title $themeName -WebTemplate "68" -SiteScripts $addSiteScript.Id -Description ""

This script successfully creates a site template but it errors when I use  "verb": "setSitePermission",
Anyone know what the correct syntax is?

Where did you find a reference to setSitePermission and UseClientIntegrationFeatures?

I've searched and can't find anything about where I discovered that. I've watched a few youtube vids on how to do it, so it might be there, but can't remember. Is there a way to disable this feature?

In case you didn't know, $schema will be interpreted as a powershell variable instead of a literal string in a expandable string "...". This will be a problem, your here-string should be @'...'@ instead of @"..."@ notice the single quotes instead of double.

@SantiagoSquarzon - thanks. Have you any idea on how to disable the UseClientIntegrationFeatures for every new template?
